# List of invalid feeds

Tags: rss, simplepie

I am planning to use SimplePie to aggregate lots of RSS.

I was unable to find a way how I can display the list of invalid feeds. Those feeds where a actual rss/atom feed was not found or data could not be extracted.

Can you please help me?

I just want to know which of the feeds set in the set_feed_url are invalid.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. I believe SimplePie will yield and error when you're fetching feeds that have gone 404 or are not feeds anymore. Make sure you catch this error. Have you considered Superfeedr too?

Comment: I have a big list of feeds...from time to time they might not work. I would like to have change to get a list of those feeds that do not work. Those that either give a 404 or their content cannot be identified. The initial validation gives up only a warning if something is wrong with one of the feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I call $feed->error() after calling $feed->init(), which returns an array with any feeds that had errors. You can use that information to remove the feeds from your list.